# How can I test/validate an RTMP endpoint and/orstream key

Tags: rtmp, live-streaming

We have a series of cloud servers running OBS that we spin up ad-hoc, on behalf of our users, in order to produce live streams for them.

However, before spinning up servers, we want to be sure that the RTMP endpoint and/or credentials they've provided us are valid. Is this possible to do without actually initializing a full blown stream?

The RTMP spec suggests there is a handshake step and a connection step, prior to streaming, but TCP/IP is beyond my realm of expertise, and I've scoured up and down for libraries that might help with this to no avail.

I've attempted using CLI tools like ffmpeg to connect to RTMP endpoints, but this only works if we actually stream data as well, and ideally would like to stop just shy of starting the actual stream.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rtmpdump` to make a connection to your RTMP Server and check the response, here is a working example:

```
RTMP_URL="rtmp://server-url/live/stream-name"
RTMP_APP="live"
RTMP_USER="username"
RTMP_PASS="password"

# try to connect and check if the server is running
if rtmpdump -r $RTMP_URL -a $RTMP_APP -v -o /dev/null 2>&1 | grep -q "Connected..."; then
  echo "server is running"

  # check if the credentials are correct
  if rtmpdump -r $RTMP_URL -a $RTMP_APP -u $RTMP_USER -p $RTMP_PASS -v -o /dev/null 2>&1 | grep -q "Connected..."; then
    echo "credentials are valid"
  else
    echo "invalid credentials"
    exit 1
  fi
else
  echo "server is not running"
  exit 1
fi

exit 0
```

If you want to use a stream key instead of user/pass combination, you can omit the `-u` and `-p` arguments and set the key as path in the RTMP URL.